# Free songs for video production

Tags: video, music, copyright

I would like to make a video with songs in the background. I'm mostly interested about classic music, but other genres as well. I know of Creative Commons. However, I was wondering if there are recordings of famous songs available for free (perhaps, old recordings?).

Comment: -1: This is a shopping cart question. It's difficult to write an answer that isn't a list of links that will eventually go out of date.

Comment: @FriendofGeorge (and @Kevin) Is this really a shopping recommendation? It's asking whether such a thing exists, not asking for a specific source. Sources are, at best, supporting detail in an answer, not an answer in and of themselves.

Comment: You are probably right.  However it is a duplicate of this question:  http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/5518/how-to-find-royalty-free-music?rq=1 Which is a duplicate of this question: http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/5214/where-to-find-free-music

Answer (score 2):

You can download [royalty-free](http://www.locutortv.es/musicalibredederechos.htm) songs for video production or [poems free](http://www.amorypoesia.es) for video production. It is no charge

Answer (score 1):

Look for music released with Creative Commons licences.